# Anonymous checkout doesn't properly work

Tags: commerce, users

Anonymous users are supposed to have access to Commerce cart/checkout by default. In my current project cart remains empty for anonymous users, even if an order is created. When an anonymous user clicks on *Add to cart*, a new order is correctly created, with the *Owned by anonymous* status. This is fine, but:

- While the current product page is reloaded as expected, the rule displaying the default message (*Foo was added to your cart*) is not fired
- If I manually go to /cart, I get the *Cart is empty* message. /checkout returns a 404 error.
- `$_SESSION` remains empty (I precise this because of [`commerce_checkout_access()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.module/function/commerce_checkout_access/7)).

  ```
  if (empty($_SESSION['commerce_cart_orders']) || !in_array($order->order_id, $_SESSION['commerce_cart_orders'])) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  ```

In fact, it seems that in anonymous context, the order cannot be seen.

How do I debug why the cart remains empty, and the order isn't visible  to anonymous users?

My config: clean step by step Commerce install, not Kickstart; some [custom line items](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) ;  *Access checkout / View own orders of any type / View any product of any type* permissions granted for anonymous.

Comment: did you check permission of check out ?

Comment: Yes Zhilevan, I did, tks. I even tried more exotic permissions with order & products, no way

Comment: Check your Rules configuration ( `admin/config/workflow/rules` ) for add to cart etc.. It's possible something there may be the cause.

Comment: Just to try and isolate the issue it might be worth disabling some modules. I'd start with any home-grown modules you have, then all the modules you've added since the working backup, and finally any caching modules you might have installed. (Don't forget to clear caches before testing.) Could you confirm if [`commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_submit()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_submit/7) is actually run, and if so step through it and report back on where things go a bit wrong?!

Comment: @DavidThomas Tks David I already checked, there are few rules, most of them default Commerce rules, and I deactivated all to test & make sure

Comment: If $_SESSION remains empty, sounds like this might be a cookie-related problem. Another thing to consider would be aggressive page caching of some description - a forward proxy perhaps, or something overriding Drupal's defaults.

Comment: Can you check if the products are enabled?

Comment: @Andy, tks Andy yep I'm currently narrowing the search between all backups, then I'll check in the version history the changes btw the last functional & the first bugged on. I'll post an edit as soon as I have new pists. I added a watchdog to  `commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_submit()` and I confirm it's running (and as said in the question, from admin side, an anon. order is created). I'll report my searches result this evening or before :)

Comment: Can you find the point, where the data for your cart is loaded ? Install XDebug and place a break-point there. Than "Step-by-Step" Debug until the point, where you get the wrong / empty result ...

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong, thanks ! In fact the anonymous user was not in the users table :(

Comment: @Kojo I am glad you found the issue. I'll add that to my list of causes for horrible errors!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Happy end, and stupid lost time : the lone problem was the **Anonymous user was accidentally deleted** (don't know how) ! I thank all the gentlemen who tried to help me to debug.

The uid 0 must absolutely be there. If you encounter such case, simply insert an empty row in users table via phpmyadmin or [run these 2 queries](https://www.drupal.org/node/1029506) (for D7) :

```
insert into users (name, pass, mail, theme, signature, language, init, timezone) values ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
update users set uid = 0 where name = '';
```

Meanwhile, I've read many things about *Commerce checkout* to make sure I was doing right. I share some clues below in case it could help somebody else.

**A common issue for empty cart page** (and other Commerce Views issues where user can't see products) is due to *Referenced Product Relationship*: 2 solutions may work depending on your config :

- In the View's advanced settings fieldset, disable SQL rewriting.
- Enable the not-totally-secure `View any product of any type` permission. This is [discussed & patched here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1303194). If you have *Commons* distribution, you’ll have to disable [paranoia](https://www.drupal.org/project/paranoia) (disable with Drush only, it's not visible in the module list).

**Important permissions to grant** (admin/people/permissions) :

- Anonymous :

  - Checkout => Access checkout
  - Order => Create orders of any type  / Create orders
- Authenticated : same ones, plus

  - Order => View own orders of any type / View own orders

**Default behavior in Drupal Commerce :**

Anonymous users can add a product to cart, checkout (filling email, name and address), review and complete order. Some documentation to read : [Checkout: Anonymous vs. Authenticated](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/checkout-anonymous-vs-authenticated)  and [Anonymous Carts and Logged In Users](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/anonymous-carts-and-logged-users)

---

### An a few useful tips and links to enhance default checkout

- How to [auto login anonymous user that has completed checkout](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75778/in-drupal-commerce-how-do-you-auto-login-an-anonymous-user-that-has-completed-ch#75780) ? As per *duckx answer*, you can get this in 3 short steps : checking above rules, enabling [Commerce Checkout Complete Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_complete_registration) or [Commerce Immediate Login](http://drupal.org/sandbox/simongeorges/1676742), adding *the Login action* to the default Commerce "Create new account for anonymous order" Rule.
- Use [Commerce Checkout Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_login) to provide e-mail validation and an inline login form via AJAX.

  > If the e-mail address an anonymous user enters is already associated
  >   with a user account, the checkout form will expand with an optional
  >   password textfield and login button for immediate login.
- Use the popular [Commerce Checkout Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect)  to redirect anonymous users to a page where they can login or create a new account when they try to checkout. Many settings available…
- Use [Commerce Address book](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook) to allow authenticated customers to reuse
  previously entered addresses during checkout.
- How to set up an [Express checkout](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/express-checkout-drupal-commerce)  (a single page checkout process that any user - including an anonymous user - can complete in a snap)
- How to set [Different payment methods for different product types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34014/different-payment-methods-for-different-product-types)  adding a condition to the payment method rule.
- How to [create an order through Drupal Commerce API](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31187/checkout-page-not-found-when-order-created-through-drupal-commerce-api-for-not-a?rq=1)
- Use [Commerce add to cart confirmation](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_confirmation) to provide an "add to cart" confirmation dialog, shown after the customer has added a product to his cart.
- Last, [Commerce Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra) offers a bundle of features, from which *cloning Address information* from user's account (instead from previously made orders as Commerce Address book does), and adding an *extra step to checkout* so that users may log in optionally.

Answer (score 0):

find file docroot/web/sites/all/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/cart/commerce_cart.module

find function commerce_cart_get_provider and force it to load CommerceCartProviderSession class

```
/**
 * Returns the instantiated cart provider.
 */
function commerce_cart_get_provider($provider = NULL)
{
  ctools_include('plugins');

  if (empty($provider)) {
     $file = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', 'commerce_cart') . "/plugins/cart_provider/CommerceCartProviderSession.class.php";
     require_once($file);
     $class = 'CommerceCartProviderSession';
     return new $class();
    // the following line was not working
    // $provider = variable_get('commerce_cart_provider', COMMERCE_CART_DEFAULT_PROVIDER);
  }

  // Return NULL if the class could not be found.
  if (!$class = ctools_plugin_load_class('commerce_cart', 'cart_provider', $provider, 'class')) {
    return NULL;
  }

  return new $class();
}
```